# Python-Location of a letter in a two dimensional string

Tags: python

I am working on creating a playfair cipher for python and I am having trouble indexing the location of a letter in the table provided below.

```
     [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
     ['F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'Y'],
     ['K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O'],
     ['P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T'],
     ['U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Z']]
```

I was wondering how I would be able to find the location of a letter in the table which gives an output of row and column.

I've looked online for different solutions, but I can't seem to make it work properly.

Comment: "Strings" are one dimensional ("fabric" is a fairly unknown concept in programming), you have lists `:P`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
def find_index(table, letter):
    for r_index, row in enumerate(table):
        if letter in row:
            return (r_index, row.index(letter))
```

You iterate through the table, and search for the index of the letter in each row.

---

Alternatively, if you're constantly searching in the matrix, it might be more efficient to convert it to a dict so you get O(1) access:

```
def get_index_map(table):
    output = {}
    for r_index, row in enumerate(table):
        for c_index, letter in enumerate(row):
            output[letter] = (r_index, c_index)
    return output
```

Then, you can just call this function once at the start of your program, and use the returned dict to find the row and column number of each letter.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me. I believe that this will work.

Answer (score 3):

My take:

```
>>> lst = [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
...        ['F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'Y'],
...        ['K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O'],
...        ['P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T'],
...        ['U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Z']]
>>> get = "S"
>>> {x:y.index(get) for x,y in enumerate(lst) if get in y}
{3: 3}
>>> get = "V"
>>> {x:y.index(get) for x,y in enumerate(lst) if get in y}
{4: 1}
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
     ['F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'Y'],
     ['K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O'],
     ['P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T'],
     ['U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Z']]

search = "I"

for rowIdx, row in enumerate(data):
    if search in row:
        print rowIdx, row.index(search)
        break
```

**Output**

```
1 3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import product

li = [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
     ['F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'Y'],
     ['K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O'],
     ['P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T'],
     ['U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Z']]

letter = 'P'

for i, j in product(range(len(li)),range(len(li[0]))):
    if li[i][j] == letter:
        print (i,j)
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my weird way. :) Note: Python 2.7 so `/` means integer division.

```
table = [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
         ['F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'Y'],
         ['K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O'],
         ['P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T'],
         ['U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Z']]

tablestring = ''.join(''.join(row) for row in table)
x = tablestring.index('V')
i = x / (len(tablestring) / len(table))
j = x % (len(tablestring) / len(table))
print i, j
print table[i][j]
```

Prints:

```
4 1
V
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
matrix=[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
     ['F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'Y'],
     ['K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O'],
     ['P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T'],
     ['U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Z']]

def index(letter, matrix):
    for i,li in enumerate(matrix):
        try:
            j=li.index(letter)
            return i,j
        except ValueError:
            pass    

    raise ValueError("'{}' not in matrix".format(letter))

print index('H', matrix)     
# (1, 2) 
print index('a', matrix) 
# ValueError
```

Comment: Won't catching the exceptions consume more time?

Comment: I like the way you wrote this. It was easy for me to understand and helped me a lot. I appreciate the time you spent helping me.

Comment: @thefourtheye: Well it is not the *fastest* way to do it true but it is idiomatic. :-)